# How to write a piecewise regression model as a linear model?

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, matrix

Let's write the following piecewise regression model
$$y=  \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x +\epsilon ;\ \ x\le x_0 $$

$$ y=\beta_0 +\beta_1 x + \epsilon;\ \ x\gt x_0$$

When the value $x_0$ is known, this regression model is a linear model.  How to write this model in the form $Y= X\beta +\epsilon $ where $X$ is a matrix and $\beta$ is a parameter vector?

Comment: Are you thinking of something like so: http://www.r-bloggers.com/estimating-continuous-piecewise-linear-regression/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overall model has four parameters: $\alpha_0,$ $\alpha_1,$ $\beta_0,$ and $\beta_1.$  Therefore, **if a solution is at all possible, we must be able to construct four corresponding variables $z_1, z_2,$ $z_3,$ and $z_4.$**

One solution dedicates the first two parameters to the first model and the second two parameters to the second model.  Thus, when $x\le x_0,$ we may set $\mathbf z = (z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=(1,x,0,0)$ and when $x \gt x_0$ set $\mathbf z = (z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=(0,0,1,x).$  The zeros ensure the parameters for one part of the model do not affect the other part of the model.

To put it another way, for any parameter vector $\gamma = (\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3,\gamma_4)^\prime$ notice that

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf z \gamma &= (1,x,0,0)(\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3,\gamma_4)^\prime = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 x,& \ x \le x_0\\
\mathbf z \gamma &= (0,0,1,x)(\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3,\gamma_4)^\prime = \gamma_3 + \gamma_4 x,& \ x \gt x_0.
\end{aligned}$$

This is precisely the desired model with $\gamma_1=\alpha_0, \gamma_2=\alpha_1,$ $\gamma_3=\beta_0,$ and $\gamma_4=\beta_1.$  As is usual, when you assemble the observations as rows in a "model matrix" $Z,$ the model can be written $y = Z\gamma + E$ where $E$ is the vector of errors.

[image: Figure]

The $x$ values in the plot are $0, 1, 2, \ldots, 20$ and $x_0=11.$  The model matrix $Z$ is

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    1    0    0
 [3,]    1    2    0    0
 [4,]    1    3    0    0
 [5,]    1    4    0    0
 [6,]    1    5    0    0
 [7,]    1    6    0    0
 [8,]    1    7    0    0
 [9,]    1    8    0    0
[10,]    1    9    0    0
[11,]    1   10    0    0
[12,]    1   11    0    0
[13,]    0    0    1   12
[14,]    0    0    1   13
[15,]    0    0    1   14
[16,]    0    0    1   15
[17,]    0    0    1   16
[18,]    0    0    1   17
[19,]    0    0    1   18
[20,]    0    0    1   19
[21,]    0    0    1   20
```

The pattern is clear.

These data and fits were produced by the following `R` implementation of this procedure.

```R
x <- seq(0, 20)
gamma <- c(12, -1, 0, 1/2)
x0 <- 11
sigma <- 1
#
# Create the model matrix `Z` and true responses `y.`
#
Z <- cbind(x <= x0, x*(x <= x0), x > x0, x*(x > x0))
y. <- Z %*% gamma
#
# Create random responses according to the model.
#
set.seed(17)
y <- y. + rnorm(length(y.), 0, sigma)
#
# Find the least-squares fit.
#
fit <- lm.fit(Z, y)
#
# Plot the data, model, and fit.
#
plot(x, y, type="n", ylim=c(0,15), main="Data, True Model (Red), and Fit (Dashed Blue)")

f <- function(x, gamma) cbind(x <= x0, x*(x <= x0), x > x0, x*(x > x0)) %*% gamma
curve(f(x, gamma), add=TRUE, n=2001, col="Red", lwd=2)
curve(f(x,  fit$coefficients), add=TRUE, n=2001, lty=3, col="Blue", lwd=2)
abline(v = x0, lwd=2, col="Gray")
text(x0, 14, expression(x[0]), pos=4)
text(1,1, expression(y==gamma[1]+gamma[2]*x+epsilon), pos=4)
text(19,1, expression(y==gamma[3]+gamma[4]*x+epsilon), pos=2)
points(x, y, pch=19)
```

Answer (score 5):

For a known discontinuous break point $x_0$, the following piecewise regression model:

$$y=  \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x +\epsilon ;\ \ x\le x_0 $$

$$y=\beta_0 +\beta_1 x + \epsilon;\ \ x\gt x_0$$

can instead be expressed using an indicator function of $x$ and $x_0$ for the change in intercept, and a hinge function of $x_i$ and $x_0$ for the change in slope:

$$y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{x}x_{i} + \beta_{0\text{c}}I(x_{i} \ge x_0) + \beta_{x\text{c}} \max(x_i - x_0,0) + \varepsilon_{i}$$

**Explanation**

**Change in intercept:** If $x_i < x_0$, then $I(x_i \ge x_0) = 0$, so the $\beta_{0\text{c}}I(x_{i} \ge x_0)$ term also equals $0$. However, if $x_i \ge x_0$, then $I(x_i \ge x_0) = 1$, and the $\beta_{0\text{c}}I(x_{i} \ge x_0)$ term equals $\beta_{0\text{c}}$… which is just a constant, so the intercept for values at $x_0$ and higher equals $\beta_0 + \beta_{0\text{c}}$.

**Change in slope:** If $x_i < x_0$, then $\max(x_i - x_0,0) = 0$, so the $\beta_{x\text{c}} \max(x_i - x_0,0)$ term also equals $0$. However, if $x_i \ge x_0$, then the $\max(x_i - x_0,0)$ term increases at exactly the same rate as $x_i$: a one-unit increase in $x_i$ corresponds to a one-unit increase in $\max(x_i-x_0,0)$. For example, if $x_i = x_0 + 2$, then $\max(x_i - x_0,0)=2$. The effect of $x$ on $y$ when $x_i < x_0$ is just $\beta_x$, but the effect of $x$ on $y$ changes from $\beta_{x}$ to $\beta_x + \beta_{x\text{c}}$ for values of $x_i \ge x_0$.

**A single linear model**

You can thus create a single linear model with two new variables, where $x_{1i} = x_i$ and, say, $x_{2i} = I(x_{1i} \ge x_0)$, and $x_{3i} = \max(x_{1i}-x_0,0)$ and estimate (e.g., using OLS):

$$\boldsymbol{y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_x x_{1i} + \beta_{0\text{c}}x_{2i} + \beta_{x\text{c}}x_{3i} + \varepsilon_{i}} = BX_{i} + \varepsilon_{i}$$